# How to disable space when using pandoc with Chinese characters?

Tags: vim, space, pandoc, cjk

When we use vim, we always set vim to limit the number of characters per line. Like this

```
set cc=80
set fo=+tMn
```

So if I convert a markdown file to a docx file, pandoc will automatically place a space at the tail of every line, which is nice for English docs.

But for chinese characters, it is wired for a space in a single sentence. So is there any methods to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is solution I found, from the [MANUAL](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html).

> Extension: `east_asian_line_breaks`
>
> Causes newlines within a paragraph to be ignored, rather than being treated as spaces or as hard line breaks, when they occur between two East Asian wide characters. This is a better choice than `ignore_line_breaks` for texts that include a mix of East Asian wide characters and other characters.